# Hiding a Master Shape in Stencil in Visio

Tags: hide, visio, shapes, stencils

Is it possible to hide a master shape in your stencil so that a user cannot drag and drop it on their diagram, while still allowing me to use that object in the diagram programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting the Master's [Hidden Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb435878%28v=office.11%29.aspx). This can't be set the the UI but it is easy to set in the VBA Immediate window with a statement like this:

```
Visio.ActiveDocument.Masters("MyMaster").Hidden = True
```